# cannot decode json laravel

Tags: laravel, react-native

I am developing a react native app where i have table data to send controller in laravel.Here is my react native code for table data post request to controller

```
var userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userToken");
    fetch('http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/tajroof/public/api/createSales', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Authorization:`Bearer ${userToken}`,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(
           this.state.resdata

        )

        }).then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {

            console.log(responseJson)
                // Alert.alert(responseJson.status);
                // this.setState({modalVisible:false})

        }).catch((error) => {
            alert(error);
        });
```

}

here is my controller with json decode

```
$data =json_decode($request->getContent(),true);
print_r($data);
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        echo $value["category_id"] . ", " . $value["pname"] . "<br>";
      }
```

but i am getting response

```
Array[
Object{
"category_id":1,
"pname":"Potato"
},
Object{
"category_id":2,
"pname":"Oil"
}
]
```

if i try with another code in laravel controller like this

```
$data=$request->getContent();
    $data=response()->json($data);
```

then i got response like this

```
[{"category_id":1,"pname":"potato"},{"category_id":2,"pname":"oil"}]
```

In both cases i am unable to fetch category id ,pname(product name).Please help ..Your help will appreciate

Comment: can you please share the json string?

Comment: [{"id":40,"category_id":2,"product_id":5},{"id":51,"category_id":2,"product_id":5}]

Comment: if I put this json raw in laravel like and loop i got every value but when it comes with variable i am unable to fetch

Comment: if i decode and return i got Array [
  Object {
    "category_id": 2,
    "color": "Brown" },
  Object {
    "category_id": 2,
    "color": "Brown" }
]

Comment: i am unable solve..please give solution with code

Comment: i got error unexpected tokek '<' json parse error

Comment: some time i am getting Array [
  Object {
    "category_id": 2,
    "color": "Brown" },
  Object {
    "category_id": 2,
    "color": "Brown" }
] how to fetch this

Comment: Please give the full code for form and controller method.

Comment: i did another method like i fetched id and i got like Array[2,5,] and after fetch element i got 2 5...and now i want to fetch db record with these two id 2 and 5 in laravel..how it possible

Comment: There are many ways to do it. You can loop through all the ids and use `Model::find($id)` to get them individually. Or you can use `Model::findMany($id_array)` to get them. Or you can use `Model::whereIn('id', $id_array)->get();`. Use whatever you feel like. But remember `find()` only works with primary key.

Comment: my problem is that i have two id 2 and 5 and after for loop i got 25 in cosole now how i seperate 25 to 2 and 5 and assign to variable and fetch db record

Comment: You have to send the ids separately from the react-native side. Cause you can't always separate the ids from laravel. For your current case, you can divide 25 with 10 and get 2 &5 separately. But what if you have to send 12 and 3? Then you will have 123. Then you don't know which is what. So, send the ids separately, maybe in an array of ids. Laravel accepts input in arrays.

Comment: from my react native side i got like Array[2,5,] in console and after using for loop in laravel i got 25..so i want to separate these ids..is it issue of react native or laravel

Comment: If you are using loop then you are not getting 25. First 2 then 5. Am i correct?

Comment: yes first 2 and then 5 overall 25

Comment: Then you have them separeted already. Loop through them and fetch the data from database!